# Convert LVM logical volume to use striping?

Tags: linux, lvm

I don't want to change the size of LVM, I just want it to use striping.

We made LV on single volume, but now we want to migrate to 3 volumes, each smaller, but have the LVM stripe across all 3 of the volumes to give us optimal performance (the old, large volume will be then removed).

I can't have downtime of the server, and I'd prefer not to add mdadm to the picture.

lvextend seems to have -i option, but when I try to use it it sais I have to provide size extension too :/

Any option to make it happen?

Comment: This seems very much like the wrong approach - lvm is not built for performance, that's why you mdadm with raid0 (aside from the inherent risks of raid0 - you don't want downtime, so the data is important, but you want it on raid0, so the data is valueless? does not compute...)

Comment: The best analysis of md raid0 vs. lvm stripes is by jeff leyton http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7582/ with page 2 going into performance comparison. In short for performance md wins, but lvm is more flexible in terms of future growth, albeit not in the same stripe group.

Comment: This question is doing the opposite, converting a striped LV to a linear one: http://serverfault.com/questions/229812/is-it-possible-to-convert-striped-logical-volume-to-linear-logical-volume?rq=1. Could be helpful in figuring out your problem.

Comment: @D34DM347 thanks, that looks promising.