# Is it possible to mirror a striped LVM logical volume?

Tags: lvm

I have a striped logical volume that is currently split between two physical drives (`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`). I now want to mirror this volume onto a third device (`/dev/sdc1`) that has been added into the volume group. A number of references I have found (e.g. [Is it possible to convert striped logical volume to linear logical volume?](https://serverfault.com/questions/229812/is-it-possible-to-convert-striped-logical-volume-to-linear-logical-volume)) suggest this is possible with the following command:

```
lvconvert -m 1 /dev/volgroup/volume /dev/sdc1
```

However for me this results in the following error:

```
'--mirrors/-m' is not compatible with striped
```

Why isn't this working for me?

#### LVM version

```
LVM version:     2.02.133(2) (2015-10-30)
Library version: 1.02.110 (2015-10-30)
Driver version:  4.34.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
lvconvert -m1 /dev/volgroup/volume
```

Below is the command log of my test. I did it on loopback devices

Create 3 loopback devices

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk1 bs=1M count=100
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk2 bs=1M count=100
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk3 bs=1M count=200
[root@localhost ~]# losetup -f /root/disk1
[root@localhost ~]# losetup -f /root/disk2
[root@localhost ~]# losetup -f /root/disk3
[root@localhost ~]# losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [64768]:17900481 (/root/disk1)
/dev/loop1: [64768]:17900482 (/root/disk2)
/dev/loop2: [64768]:17900483 (/root/disk3)
```

Create PVs

```
[root@localhost ~]# pvcreate /dev/loop0
  Physical volume "/dev/loop0" successfully created
[root@localhost ~]# pvcreate /dev/loop1
  Physical volume "/dev/loop1" successfully created
[root@localhost ~]# pvcreate /dev/loop2
  Physical volume "/dev/loop2" successfully created
[root@localhost ~]# pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/loop0        lvm2 ---  100.00m 100.00m
  /dev/loop1        lvm2 ---  100.00m 100.00m
  /dev/loop2        lvm2 ---  200.00m 200.00m
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--    7.51g  40.00m
```

Create VG and LV with 2 stripes

```
vgcreate StripedVG /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
lvcreate -l +100%FREE -i2 -n StripedLV StripedVG
Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
Logical volume "StripedLV" created.
```

[image]

Format and mount

```
mkfs /dev/mapper/StripedVG-StripedLV
mount /dev/mapper/StripedVG-StripedLV /mnt
```

Now let's add our 3rd PV to VG

```
vgextend StripedVG /dev/loop2
Volume group "StripedVG" successfully extended
```

And now convert

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvconvert -m1 StripedVG/StripedLV
  StripedVG/StripedLV: Converted: 0.0%
  StripedVG/StripedLV: Converted: 83.3%
  StripedVG/StripedLV: Converted: 100.0%
```

Remove striped part from mirror

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvconvert -m0 StripedVG/StripedLV /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
  Logical volume StripedLV converted.
```

[image]

And now get rid of the /dev/loop0 and /dev/loop1

```
[root@localhost ~]# vgreduce StripedVG /dev/loop0
  Removed "/dev/loop0" from volume group "StripedVG"
[root@localhost ~]# vgreduce StripedVG /dev/loop1
  Removed "/dev/loop1" from volume group "StripedVG"
[root@localhost ~]# pvremove /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
  Labels on physical volume "/dev/loop0" successfully wiped
  Labels on physical volume "/dev/loop1" successfully wiped
```

So what we have finally is this

[image]

**Edit 1:**
What I described above works on CentOS 6, but doesn't work on CentOS 7.
I guess in CentOS 7 this rule kicks in.
Since striped != linear, it fails.

[image]

I just recompiled lvm rpm package from source but added extra debug

[image]

And here is output

```
[root@localhost x86_64]# lvconvert -m1 StripedVG/StripedLV
  '--mirrors/-m' is not compatible with striped
  arg_count = 1

  seg_is_linear = 0

  seg_is_mirrored = 0
```

So basically all 3 conditions evaluate to true and we enter error handling block.

```
arg_count=1 
!seg_is_linear = !(0) = 1
!seg_is_mirrored = !(0) = 1
```

**Edit 2**:
I found solution for CentOS 7. Instead of RAID 1 - we need to use --type mirror

```
lvconvert --type mirror -m 1 StripedVG/StripedLV
```

[image]

And then convert it to Linear and chose which PVs to remove

```
lvconvert -m0 StripedVG/StripedLV /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
```

[image]

Comment: This works on CentOS 6.x, however same sequence of commands doesn't work on CentOS 7.x. There is an interesting KB from RedHat https://access.redhat.com/solutions/227433 which goes other way. It says that there are no lvm tools to convert linear to striped.

Comment: Interesting. So it used to be possible (hence guides from around 2012 say it works), but later versions prevent it. Any idea why this change was made? Could the functionality have been dangerous?

Comment: In CentOS 7 we need to use --type mirror versus just -m1. -m1 in CentOS 7 assumes RAID 1. I added EDIT 2 to show CentOS 7 syntax.